# filter_var or custom function for email validation in php

Tags: php, validation, email

Which solution is better, using the built in validation `filter_var('email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` or a custom function?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on your custom function ;)

Comment: I'm using this one: http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/rfc822.phps at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom validation gives you more control over how far you want to go with this. What is and is not valid as an e-mail address is more complex than you might think, and most of the time, it is better to be too lax with this than too strict. After all, a syntactically valid e-mail address doesn't guarantee that the account actually exists, let alone that it's being actively used. Something like, it must contain one @, at least one dot after the @, at least one character before the @, and none of the illegal characters, is probably good enough in most cases.

Comment: PHP does not validate email addresses according to the official RFC (I can't find a reference for this right now, but it came up here recently). Even though `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is probably good enough most of the time, I'd recommend against it and either go with an RFC compliant checker or, as you said, take it easy.

Comment: Oh, here we go: http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/filter/logical_filters.c Look for the regex in `php_filter_validate_email`. It's much too short to be fully RFC compliant. :)

Comment: My point exactly. RFC compliant doesn't mean it exists and works. Also, I'd be surprised to hear that all mail agents are RFC compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Filter var for email remove all characters, except **letters**, **digits** and `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@.[] ``. Now it is up to your whether you want to go with this filtration or create a custom solution.

And here is an excellent article on that:

[Input Validation: Using filter_var() Over Regular Expressions](http://mattiasgeniar.be/2009/02/07/input-validation-using-filter_var-over-regular-expressions/)

Comment: The *santizing* filter does, but not the *validating* filter. Without being sanitized, a "valid" email (according to the filter) can still contain characters other than those listed above.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's filter_var might be satisfactory for most applications, but if you want to compare performance and validity, look at this site http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585 to understand what RFC 2822-compliance means.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to use my free PHP function `is_email()` to validate addresses. It's available [here](http://isemail.info).

It will ensure that an address is fully RFC 5321 compliant. It can optionally also check whether the domain actually exists.

You shouldn't rely on a validator to tell you whether a user's email address actually exists: some ISPs give out non-compliant addresses to their users, particularly in countries which don't use the Latin alphabet. More in my essay about email validation here: http://isemail.info/about.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while Googling, 
Hope this explains you better

http://www.addedbytes.com/code/email-address-validation/